# Heroku on Cygwin is logging some weird stuff, looks like "mysql --help"

Tags: mysql, heroku, cygwin

I'm using cygwin and every time I call on heroku, it outputs what looks like the help return of msql twice, then works as normal:

```
    Kenneth@Forge ~ $ heroku
    MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for CYGWIN (x86_64) using readline 6.3
    Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.

    Usage: MySQL [OPTIONS] [database]
      -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
      -I, --help          Synonym for -?
      --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                          'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                          and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                          --disable-auto-rehash.
                          (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
      -A, --no-auto-rehash
                          No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                          table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                          mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
```

... and so on, ending with ...

```
    secure-auth                       FALSE
    show-warnings                     FALSE
    plugin-dir                        (No default value)
    default-auth                      (No default value)
```

then repeating the same as above, then working as normal. Hours of searching has yielded nothing, nor has uninstalling and reinstalling heroku. I tried to look in the heroku files to find out what's doing this, but I'm pretty far out of my depth. Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what the issue was, MySQL added two items to my path that had an & in them that Linux didn't like, something like "MySQL thing 1.0 & MySQL thing 2.0". When checking the path, Linux interpreted everything past the ampersand as a separate argument, and since it was an invalid one, it displayed the help options.